# get the desired name split in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

how can I customize the file name that uses the "-" sign so that it doesn't disappear after running the code below indeed in the code below it removes after the "-" but there is something that I don't need to remove.
So I want the result to be like in the screenshot that I marked in yellow. Can I make an exception?
Thanks

[image: Desired result]

```
Sub GetFileName2()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim arr1() As String
    Dim arr2() As String
    Dim arr3() As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'   Find last row in column A with data
    Sheets("Master").Select
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'   Pre-format column C for text
    Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "@"
'   Loop through every cell in column A starting in row 2
    For Each Rng In Range("A2:A" & lr)
        arr1 = Split(Rng.Value, "\")
        Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = arr1(UBound(arr1, 1))
        arr2 = Split(arr1(UBound(arr1, 1)), "(")
        arr3 = Split(arr2(0), "-")
'       If first member of array is blank, choose the second
        If Left(arr2(0), 1) = "-" Then
            Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Replace(arr2(0), ".jpg", "")
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value = Replace(arr3(0), ".jpg", "")
        End If
    Next Rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite , this is not an error data or image but shows the problem and the desired result

Comment: @Malf You can use `if strVal like "*-*-*" then...` to "match" patterns etc

Comment: @milo5m , thank you for your reply, can you answer it according to my code so that I understand

Comment: You may miss some cases from your question, but if you understand that independent of the way you realized the mistake, you **should edit your question and correct there the strings you missed in terms of explaining how to be processed**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated according to comments*

I've used regular expressions, since it was easier to me.

```
Sub GetFileName()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long '# of rows
    Dim columnA
    Dim columnBC
    
    'assumes activesheet, it's better to be explicit but...
    c = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If c = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    columnA = Range("A1:A" & c).Value2
    ReDim columnBC(1 To c, 1 To 2)
    
    With CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "^(\d+-\d+-\d+|[^-\(]+)(?=.*\..*$)"
        For i = 2 To UBound(columnBC)
            columnBC(i, 1) = Mid(columnA(i, 1), InStrRev(columnA(i, 1), "\") + 1)
            With .Execute(columnBC(i, 1))
                If .Count > 0 Then
                    columnBC(i, 2) = Trim(.Item(0))
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    
    Range("B1:C" & c).Value2 = columnBC
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks your reply for the problem is perfect but if your code causes other problems.`\\server-pc\catalog\catalog test FINAL\AP 0801\AP 0801.jpg` should be the result code AP 0801 , `\\server-pc\catalog\catalog test FINAL\PA.2\PA.2.jpg` should be the result code PA.2 , `\\server-pc\catalog\catalog test FINAL\SSO.06\SSO.06-A.jpg` should be the result code SSO.06

Comment: thanks for your reply, `\\server-pc\catalog\catalog test FINAL\TC52(1).jpg` should be the result code TC52 but the result of your code TC52(1

Comment: thanks for your reply, `\\server-pc\catalog\catalog test FINAL\AP 0801\AP 0801.jpg` should be the result code AP 0801 but the result of your code AP 0801.jpg ,  `\\server-pc\catalog\catalog test FINAL\PA.2\PA.2.jpg` should be the result code PA.2 but the result of your code PA.2.jpg

Comment: thank you for your reply and the last edit of the answer went the way I wanted

Comment: I am proud of your efforts to answer me with your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function (just playing with arrays...):

```
Function correctJpgName(x As String)
    Dim arr, arrJ
    If x = "" Then Exit Function
    If InStr(x, "(") > 0 Then
        arr = Split(x, "(")
        correctJpgName = arr(0)
    Else
        arr = Split(x, "-"): arrJ = Split(arr(UBound(arr)), ".")
        Select Case UBound(arr)
            Case 0: correctJpgName = arrJ(0)
            Case 1: correctJpgName = arr(0)
            Case 2: arr(UBound(arr)) = arrJ(0)
                         correctJpgName = Join(arr, "-")
            Case Else: arr(UBound(arr)) = "#@$%"      'a string certainly not existing in the ot er elements
                                arr = filter(arr, "#@$%", False) 'eliminate the last aray element
                                correctJpgName = Join(arr, "-")
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

It can be tried in the next way:

```
Sub TestcorrectJpgName()
  Dim x As String
  x = "01-03-04-d.jpg"
  'x = "01-03-05.jpg"
  'x = "TC51-1.png"
  'x = "TC52(1).png"
  'x = "SSO.06-A.jpg"
  'x = "PO 34.jpg"
  Debug.Print correctJpgName(x)
End Sub
```

Please, comment line by line from bottom up and see the result.

Then, to process all column it is faster to place the range in an array, process it in memory and drop the result at the end, at once. I mean, in this way:

```
Sub CorrectJpgNamesAll()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, strName As String, arrA, arrFin, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arrA = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrA), 1 To 2)
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
       strName = Mid(arrA(i, 1), InStrRev(arrA(i, 1), "\") + 1)
       arrFin(i, 1) = strName
       arrFin(i, 2) = correctJpgName(strName)
   Next i
   'drop the processed array content at once:
   sh.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: @milo5m Where did you see such patterns **in the question**? I cannot see any of them...

Comment: @milo5m Just lake that? Which to be the rule, I mean based on what to return without extension? I do not see such a comment... Do you mean the ones placed at your answer? i will also look there, if so. In fact, looking now to his picture, no extensions are present. I only supposed that he needs it... This will simplify the code.

Comment: @FaneDuru , thank you for your answer but the results are not perfect as I expected

Comment: @Malf Please, define what "not perfect" does mean, against what you required in your question.